# Need sample code for facebook for android native application

Tags: android, facebook

I am looking for a link for integrating FB into my application. I need example code to integrate the Fb with my Android application. I need to display the posts as in native FB application. Please help me with few best links.

1. I have an other query as well. Like when i try to get the data returned from JSON service, It returns me a  tag when i look at the errorlog. why is such HTML returned. Can i get the exact JSON response or can i convert this html to JSON code.

Guide me with sample FB code example.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is Official Facebook SDK for Android as below link.

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/385/

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/